# Derivation of $ISO(p,q)$ from $SO(p,q+1)$ by contraction?

Tags: group-theory

In [this](http://arxiv.org/abs/0810.1019) preliminaty book it says on page 261 that one can obtain inhomogenous special orthogonal group $ISO(p,q)$ from the special orthogonal group $SO(p,q+1)$ from a so-called contraction which means 
rescaling some generators by a parameters $\epsilon$ and then taking the limit $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$ or $\epsilon \rightarrow \infty$.

I dont understand how this works exactly. What does get contracted in this process? Could somebody spell out some more details, at best by means ot the example at hand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Contractions* are defined for Lie groups, Lie algebras and algebraic groups, and play an important role in in mathematics and physics. For a kind of survey see [my article](http://homepage.univie.ac.at/Dietrich.Burde/papers/burde_31_deg_alg_groups.pdf). The easiest example is on the level of Lie algebras, where one could start with the contraction of the $3$-dimensional Heisenberg Lie algebra to the abelian Lie algebra $\mathbb{R}^3$ by $g_{\epsilon}=\epsilon^{-1}{\rm id}$ and $\epsilon \to 0^+$. This reflects the well-known example of the limit process from quantum mechanics to
classical mechanics under $\hbar \rightarrow 0$, which corresponds to the contraction of the
Heisenberg Lie algebra to the Abelian one of the same dimension.

Answer (score 0):

The classic example is as we consider the plane as a limiting case of a sphere of "infinite" radius.  The isometry group of the sphere, $SO(3)$ becomes in this limit the isometry group of the plane $ISO(2)$

My way of conceptualizing this contraction is to consider it in terms of a continuous limit of subgroups of a slightly larger group $SO(p+1,n+1)$.  Consider the subgroup leaving a vector invariant (it's Little group).  If the vector is "space-like" (positive square norm) then you will find the Little group to be $SO(p,n+1)$ while if the vector is "time-like" (negative square norm) the Little group will be $SO(p+1,n)$.  At the boundary between these are the null vectors whose little groups are $ISO(p,n)$.